# How to get webcam info with WMI

Tags: python, wmi

Which class that we can obtain webcam info?
Thank

Comment: Do you need to get the device information or acquire images/video from the webcam?

Comment: I just like to get information(brand, manufacturer, device id, etc) not images/video.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may actually need [WIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630827(VS.85).aspx) -- though the URL I'm quoting is all about images, not videos, I'm sure WIA also has video functionality, I just can't find good docs on that!-(